# Swift fatal error: Index out of range

Tags: arrays, swift2, fatal-error

LeetCode Easy 88 Merge Sorted Array

Question:

Given two sorted integer arrays nums1 and nums2, merge nums2 into nums1 as one sorted array.

Note:

You may assume that nums1 has enough space (size that is greater or equal to m + n) to hold additionalelements from nums2. The number of elements initialized in nums1 and nums2 are m and n respectively.

I got an error which I have commented in my code. I have printed the index2 and index3, both they are zero.They should be legal. Why I got this error?

Any help, I appreciate it. Thank you so much for your time!

```
class Solution
{
    func merge(inout nums1:[Int], _ m: Int, _ nums2:[Int], _ n: Int)
    {
        var index1 = m - 1
        var index2 = n - 1
        var index3 = m + n - 1

        while index2 >= 0 && index1 >= 0
        {
            if nums1[index1] > nums2[index2]
            {

                nums1[index3] = nums1[index1]
                index3 -= 1
                index1 -= 1


            }
            else
            {
                nums1[index3] = nums2[index2]
                index3 -= 1
                index2 -= 1
            }
        }

        while index2 >= 0
        {
            print(index2)
            print(index3)
            nums1[index3] = nums2[index2] // fatal error: Index out of range
            index3 -= 1
            index2 -= 1
        }

    }
}



let test1 = Solution()
var haha = [Int]()
haha = []
test1.merge(&haha,0, [1],1)
print(haha)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your variable `nums1` is a 0-element array.  So there isn't space for you to make the assignment.  That is, `index3=0` and you're using that to point to the first element of `nums1`, but there is not first element.

If, for example, you change:

```
haha = []
```

to:

```
haha = [0]
```

then your the array `nums1` will have a 0-th element inside the method.

Comment: Thank you so much! It totally makes sense to me. Appreciate your help!